# How to write a TestNg class in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

I moved from eclipse to Intellij but I am not able to write a Test with @Test annotation of TestNG. It was very simple in eclipse but I am not finding any documentation about the same in intellij website.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using build system (but I would definitely recommend to do it) you can add TestNG library as a jar dependency.

- download the latest version from maven central - [org.testng](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng)
- add it as a library to Intellij IDEA project

Instructions how to add jar to Intellij project you can find in this question: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Then, this jar will be indexed by Intellij IDEA and you will be able to execute tests using TestNG.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrii Abramov